# Linear Transformation Inverses

Tags: linear-transformations

For each of the following linear transformations, find the inverse if it exists, or explain why there is no inverse.

(a) T : R
3 → R
3 where T(v) is the reflection of v around the plane x + 2y + 3z = 0

Alright so I know I have to take (1, 2, 3) and see what the reflection of v does to that, but I don't know how to do that.

Comment: $T$ is its own inverse. That's true in general of reflections, right? To find the image of a point, draw the line perpendicular to the plane that passes through the point. The image is the point on the line that is the same distance from the plane but on the other side of the plane. (Of course, if the point is in the plane, it equals its own reflection.)

Comment: @MPW So does that give me x - 2y + 3z after the reflection?

Comment: For $v=(1,2,3)$ it gives you $T(v)=-v$ because $v$ is ortogonal to the plane. It will not be usefull.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier than that. The inverse $T^{-1}$ is the operator that put $T^{-1}(T(v))$ for all $v$. In the case of a reflection, like this one, the inverse is itself. You just have to check it.

Notice that a reflection is linear if and only if the plane pass through $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: So I just find the inverse of T like a normal function?

Comment: I just asume you use the definition of reflection, not by formulae.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not satisfied by my previous answer you can use matrix representation. The matrix will be orthogonal with determinant $−1$. In this case:
$$M=I-2
\left(\begin{array}\\
1&2&3 \\
2&4&6 \\
3&6&9 \\
\end{array}\right),$$
then, it is invertible. **You can check that $M^2=I$.**

Here I put $I=\left(\begin{array}\\
1&0&0 \\
0&1&0 \\
0&0&1 \\
\end{array}\right)$ for identity.

[image: Answer to a coment: how to obtain $M$]

For $M^2=I$, let say
$$Q=
\left(\begin{array}\\
1&2&3 \\
2&4&6 \\
3&6&9 \\
\end{array}\right).$$
Notice that $(I-2Q)(I-2Q)=I-4Q+4Q^2=I-4(Q-Q^2),$

Comment: How did you come up with that matrix?

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused

Comment: You can follow two variants: 1) noticing that if $O$ is the original and $R$ the image, $P=2O'-O$ being $O'$ the projection of $O$ in the plane and doing the algebra, or 2) cheating: [Reflection(wikipedia)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_(mathematics))

Comment: Can you show me like an example?

Comment: I will add a figure.

Comment: Okay so I just have to find the inverse of the matrix you gave me?

Comment: Sorry, the figure is a little HUGE, but I hope it help.

Comment: How do I actually solve for the inverse. I understand the graph now

Comment: just multiply $M$ times $M$ and check $M^2=I$, this means that $M=M^{-1}$.

Comment: So for I-2 in M do i subtract the matrix multiplied by 2 by the identity matrix?